# order a column within each group

Tags: r

I have a large data set like this:

```
 df <- data.frame(group = c(rep(1, 3), rep(5, 3)), member = c(30, 10, 22, 21, 44, 15)) 

 group member
 1     30
 1     10
 1     22
 5     21
 5     44
 5     15
```

...

I want to order member within each group. The expected output should look like this:

```
 group member
 1     10
 1     22
 1     30
 5     15
 5     21
 5     44
```

...

Does anyone have idea about realizing this?

Comment: how large is your actual dataset?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "with" function : first argument is your dataframe and second one is what you want to do with it : order by variable "group" then by variable "member".

```
df[with(df,order(group,member)),]
```

Comment: Please explain how this solves the problem; this will help future readers understand your reasoning.

Comment: Even if your answer is correct, with any explanation the answer is low-quality because it may not be very useful to others with similar-but-slightly-different issues.  Thanks for your additional effort.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ddply` from plyr package

```
> library(plyr)
> ddply(df, .(group), mutate, member=sort(member))
  group member
1     1     10
2     1     22
3     1     30
4     5     15
5     5     21
6     5     44
```